# Problems using zdir in contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, matplotlib-3d

I'm attempting to plot 2D slices from a 3D scatter plot using matplotlib, and am having problems with the `zdir` argument.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal


mean = np.array([0, 0, 0])
covariance_matrix = np.array([[1, 0.5, 0.2],
                               [0.5, 1, 0.3],
                               [0.2, 0.3, 1]])


x1=np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x1,x1,x1)
pos = np.column_stack((x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel()))
pdf_values = multivariate_normal.pdf(pos, mean=mean, cov=covariance_matrix)
pdf_values = pdf_values.reshape(50, 50, 50)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x_flat, y_flat, z_flat = x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z.flatten()
pdf_flat = pdf_values.flatten()
threshold=0.03
inside_sphere = pdf_flat > threshold
from matplotlib import cm
ax.scatter(x_flat[inside_sphere], y_flat[inside_sphere], z_flat[inside_sphere], c=pdf_flat[inside_sphere], marker='.',s=1)

ax.contour(X=x[:,:,25], Y=y[:,:,25], Z=pdf_values[:,:,25], zdir='z',offset=-1.5 , cmap=cm.coolwarm)
#Problems begin when changing zdir to a non-z argument
ax.contour(X=x[25,:,:], Y=z[25,:,:], Z=pdf_values[25,:,:], zdir='y', cmap=cm.coolwarm)

plt.show()
```

This generates the following image
[image]

But where is the Y projection? If you comment out the other two lines you get this:

[image]

Changing the `zdir` argument to "z" turns into a more recognisable contour plot. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

If you want to display the contour of the plot on the `y-axis`, then you should change the `Y` parameter in `ax.contour(...)` to the array of `pdf_values`. Keep the `X` and `Z` parameters equal to the `x` and `z` arrays, respectively. This can be applied to the other axes as well.

[image: contour on all three axes]

Your code works for the case where `zdir='z'` because you set `Z=pdf_values[...]` already. Simply apply this method to the other axes!

Note: Setting the axes limits equal to the offsets in the contour function gives the appearance that the contours are on the 'walls' of the figure.

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal


mean = np.array([0, 0, 0])
covariance_matrix = np.array([[1, 0.5, 0.2],
                               [0.5, 1, 0.3],
                               [0.2, 0.3, 1]])


x1=np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x1,x1,x1)
pos = np.column_stack((x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel()))
pdf_values = multivariate_normal.pdf(pos, mean=mean, cov=covariance_matrix)
pdf_values = pdf_values.reshape(50, 50, 50)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x_flat, y_flat, z_flat = x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z.flatten()
pdf_flat = pdf_values.flatten()
threshold=0.03
inside_sphere = pdf_flat > threshold
from matplotlib import cm
ax.scatter(x_flat[inside_sphere], y_flat[inside_sphere], z_flat[inside_sphere], c=pdf_flat[inside_sphere], marker='.',s=1)

ax.contour(X=x[:,:,25], Y=y[:,:,25], Z=pdf_values[:,:,25], zdir='z',offset=-2.5 , cmap=cm.coolwarm)


###### EDITS START HERE ######
#Change which axis is set to the 'pdf_values' array
ax.contour(X=x[25,:,:], Y=pdf_values[25,:,:], Z=z[25,:,:], offset=2.5, zdir='y', cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.contour(X=pdf_values[:,25,:], Y=y[:,25,:], Z=z[:,25,:], offset=-2.5, zdir='x', cmap=cm.coolwarm)

# Set axes limits so that contour appears on the figure 'wall'
ax.set_xlim(-2.5,2.5)
ax.set_ylim(-2.5,2.5)
ax.set_zlim(-2.5,2.5)
######  EDITS END HERE  ######

plt.show()
```